# Calculate Time Difference Between php ATOM date strings with different timezones

Tags: php, date, timezone, datediff

I'm trying to run a bunch of dates through a loop.

For each loop item I have:

- An `ATOM` time (always UTC+2)
- An `ATOM` time (varies UTC+/-x)

For instance:

1. **post date** = 2017-05-13T01:51:51+02:00 - **future date** = 2017-05-13T01:00:00-03:00
2. **post date** = 2017-04-22T19:26:31+02:00 - **future date** = 2017-04-29T05:00:00+01:00

What I would like to know:

- Within a foreach loop, how do I get the time difference for each relative 'future date' against the 'post date'
- I'm not sure if I need to convert each string to UTC or use an offset

I've already used `date_default_timezone_set()` to set each respective date (the 'post date' and 'future date'

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Datetime functions are very limited in PHP, if I have to do anything interesting with dates, I always install moment.php to help me do it: https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php  if you need more information than that, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks @pendo. Normally I use moment.js, but in this case I'm running a cron job, so I'm not running client-side scripting (rather pulling values from a database)

Comment: Well, maybe it's your choice of words, but I'm confused.  moment.php is not the same as moment.js.  It's a library for server side date manipulation.  Click that link and check it out and let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: Ah, sorry (long day). Will check that out and thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding, I was referring to the .js plugin and should've done better   reading.  Thanks again, will check it out and post the solution back if I can manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a DateTime class using an ATOM it will all be done for you. All you need to do is take a `diff`. For example

```
$postdate = '2017-05-13T01:50:50+02:00';
$futuredate = '2017-05-13T01:51:51-03:00';

$pd = new DateTime($postdate);
$fd = new DateTime($futuredate);

echo $pd->format(DateTime::ATOM) . PHP_EOL;
echo $fd->format(DateTime::ATOM) . PHP_EOL;

$diff = $pd->diff($fd);

echo $diff->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minute %s seconds');
```

Generates the result

```
2017-05-13T01:50:50+02:00
2017-05-13T01:51:51-03:00
0 years 0 months 0 days 5 hours 1 minute 1 seconds
```